# Should .last_build_id be commited?

Tags: git, flutter

I was wondering if `.last_build_id` file should be commited since everytime I'm testing locally it creates a new hash.

Comment: When you create a new project using flutter create, it will add .last_build_id to the .gitignore so @rasengan__'s answer is correct

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I do not think it is necessary to commit this. This is kind of like a binary file itself, everytime you make a change and run a program, the file *will* change.
`last_build_id` should be put into the `.gitignore`.

Best

Comment: Note that the file is already ignored in the template .gitignore.tmpl file : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app/.gitignore.tmpl#L25

Answer (score 5):

Have you a `.gitignore`-File? If yes, I would prefer to add default gitignore settings for *flutter* projects in your own gitignore-file.

Here an example how my gitignore looks like for a flotter project (inkl. */ios/Flutter/.last_build_id*):

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Exceptions to above rules.
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
```

You can also add specific settings (files or folder) and edit the gitignore. But on this website [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io/) you can generate a gitignore for flutter with the respective content.

Comment: I think gitignore.io is useful tool you can search for flutter and it will give you ready git ignore file. But I'm not sure how up to date will be that .gitignore file for flutter at (gitignore.io)